# 4.25" x 6" Postcards - 4-up on a page

Tags: adobe-indesign, paper-size, configuration

We've recently been doing 4-up postcards at 4.25" x 5.5" on 8.5 x 11" paper and now we want to get that extra .5" of real estate but would still like to get 4,6-up on paper. What have you done to accomplish this. I feel like this is basic math and configurations with different paper sizes but I can't seem to figure it out, what am i missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you possibly add a picture of what you're talking about? It would help clarify your question a lot. I'm a bit confused at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an 8.5" x 12" sheet for 4-up in a block..... (You *could* use a "legal" size which is 8.5 x 14" and then trim the extra 2" off).

.... or you could configure it for 6" x 18" sheet for 4-up vertically ....

... or a 4.25 x 24" sheet for 4-up horizontally....

Not *really* sure where the confusion lies.

You **can't** fit 4-up on a standard 8.5 x 11" sheet if each piece must be 4.25 x 6".

To calculate the total dimensions, merely multiply the existing dimension by the number of repeats... so 2-4.25 = 8", 2-6" = 12", thus 4-up (2 horizontal and 2 vertical) = 8.5 x12"